# How to navigate in a flattened structure firebase with FirebaseRecyclerViewAdapter

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need navigate in a flattened firebase structure and get data and charge a recycler view

This is a sample structure of firebase

**Report.json structure:**

```
{
   "time_stamp_id_report": {
    "description": "uma descrição aqui",
    "title": "Um titulo aqui"
   }
 }
```

And this is my adapter

```
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Report, ViewHolderReport> adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Report, ViewHolderReport>(Report.class,
    R.layout.layout_report_card_list, ViewHolderReport.class, ref) {
    @Override
    protected void populateViewHolder(ViewHolderReport viewHolderReport, Report r, int i) {
        viewHolderReport.nameReport.setText(r.getTitle());
    }
};
```

Works fine. But now I have this flattened structure:

**Report.json structure**

```
{
  "time_stamp_id_report": {
    "description": "uma descrição aqui",
    "image": {
      "image1": true,
      "image2 ": true
    },
    "title": "Um titulo aqui"
  }
}
```

**Images.json structure**

```
{
  "image1": {
    "value": "qiwuhqweouhfqwofe"
  },
  "image2": {
    "image": "quwerhqiweurqhwieurqhwei"
  }
}
```

So, how can I get the image value in the adapter of reports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change Your **Report Class** to something like this

```
public class TimeStampIdReport {
    private String description;
    private Image image;
    private String title;


    public TimeStampIdReport(){
        //must have empty contruct to bind the data
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Image getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(Image image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

}
```

Add Image class in or out side the **TimeStampIdReport** class like this

```
 public class Image {

    private Boolean image1;
    private Boolean image2;

    public Boolean getImage1() {
        return image1;
    }

    public void setImage1(Boolean image1) {
        this.image1 = image1;
    }

    public Boolean getImage2() {
        return image2;
    }

    public void setImage2(Boolean image2) {
        this.image2 = image2;
    }

}
```

Based on `getImage1()` and `getImage2()` methods you can inflate your view by calling `Firebase ref = new Firebase("YOURURL/Images");`

Hope it give some idea to you.

Comment: Hi frank, in my case I have a number not defined of imgs.